# Set user properties as firebase-admin

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-admin, firebase-queue

I have following character creation flow for the game and use firebase-admin on the server to validate data, one issue I came across is figuring out how to add user property on the server, so here is the idea:

- authenticated **user** sends character data to `/queue/create`
- *firebase-admin* server listens for changes in this `/queue/create`
- *firebase-admin* receives and validates the data for the character
- if successful *firebase-admin* pushes new character data to `/characters`
- [can't figure this one out] firebase-admin adds property to **user** like this `user.updateProfile({ character: /* id of character node created by firebase-admin */ })`

Issue here is that I have access to the user on the client, but not my admin server, yes I could set this up client side, but would rather keep such logic on the server. I am already passing uid along side character data during step 1, this is also added to a character node for further security validation.

Edit: a sub-question occurred to me while writing this, can we somehow handle user changing their own user profile data, as I believe this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add properties (also known as "claims") to a user's profile, that is currently only possible when you [mint your own tokens for that user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

For the standard providers, you can only [update the existing properties from the admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

Comment: Thank you, I believe if I create new user property on client side so I am then able to update it on admin, works? Or use display name as a hacky solution for this

Comment: There is no way to add properties to the existing providers. You can of course re-use an existing property, but I have no recommendation for or against that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`updateUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) method to update a Firebase Auth user's profile data from the Admin Node.js SDK.